# Get values from class to Hibernate configuration

Tags: java, hibernate

I have my hibernate.cfg.xml

There is field:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property> // getUser()???
```

I have class Detail.java, which has getter:

```
public String getUser() {
    return user;
}
```

How can I access that method from my hibernate configuration XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access a class property that from the hibernate.cfg.xml.

There's a way to achieve the same, by configuring a session factory programatically. Check the [hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic) about how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can access method property from configuration file.
But you can access configuration  property value from java method
```

**Try with the following code:**

```
System.out.println(sessionFactory.getConfiguration().getProperty("hibernate.connection.username"))
```

Comment: getConfiguration() doesn't seem to be a method within SessionFactory in Hibernate4, any other way to do this or maybe it moved?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Hibernate4:

```
File config = new File("src/hibernate.cfg.xml");
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(getConfigurationFile());
String url = configuration.getProperty("hibernate.connection.url");
```

Not sure why but looks like getConfiguration() method is no longer available in *org.hibernate.SessionFactory*